# Are representation isomorphisms of permutation representations necessarily permutation matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $\pi:G\rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ be its permutation representation. Let $U$ be a unitary matrix commuting with $\pi$. That is, $U$ is an automorphism of the $\mathbb{C}G$ module. The question is: is the action of $U$ necessarily a permutation on $\mathbb{C}G$, maybe up to a complex factor?

Thanks.

Comment: No. For example, the permutation representation could be trivial, in which case its automorphisms are as large as possible. (Unitary is not necessary to be a $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module automorphism, so if you want unitary you're also including an inner product and you want unitary automorphisms.)

Comment: More generally, the automorphism group of a $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module is a finite product of copies of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ (or $U(n)$ if you really insist on unitary automorphisms), one for every time an irreducible representation appears with multiplicity $n$. So your claim will be false as soon as an irreducible representation appears in a permutation representation with multiplicity greater than $1$.